# Expanding Menu-Bar Items including Sub-Menus depending on Class Name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

Say for example, if you have menu bar with this structure:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="menu1"><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="menu2"><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="menu2.1"><a href="#">Menu Item 2.1</a></li>
        <li class="subMenu2"><a href="#">Menu Sub-Menu Item 2</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="subMenu2.1"><a href="#">Menu Sub-Menu Item 2.1</a></li>
            <li class="subMenu2.2"><a href="#">Menu Sub-Menu Item 2.2</a></li>
            <li class="subMenu2.3"><a href="#">Menu Sub-Menu Item 2.3</a></li>
            <li class="subMenu2.4"><a href="#">Menu Sub-Menu Item 2.4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu2.2"><a href="#">Menu Item 2.2</a></li>
        <li class="menu2.3"><a href="#">Menu Item 2.3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And the recorded class name `subMenu2.2` is known, how would you go about in order to expanded this sub menu and its parent menu, so the contents of this menu can be viewed with an external call, rather than clicking on the menu bar itself.

So if `subMenu2.2` was the item to be viewed, then the all the contents and menu bar section with class name `menu2` would be shown or be in active state so it can be visible on the page.

Normally, to view an menu item you would work your way through the menu items, and on hover certain sub menus may be displayed.
My intended goal is to show the sub-menu or parent menu depending on the given/supplied class name.

Comment: How do you know which menu item is currently active on the page?

Comment: dont understand what exactly you want. can you please explain in detail.

Comment: The issue is that you don't know which one is active. Assume that none of the menu-items are active. Just an external call is made, rather than a click to make the menu item active.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the pages a body id and style the menu or script the active state according to that. Here is an article that explains that further. I hope this helps.
[css-tricks.com/id-your-body-for-greater-css-control-and-specificity](https://css-tricks.com/id-your-body-for-greater-css-control-and-specificity/)